# how pandas series map function return dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I try to map a function which return dataframe to each pandas Series element. But After map or apply, The result is Series instead of dataframe. What's problem?

The Series :

```
s1 = Series(['A',2,5])
```

The function:

```
df = DataFrame({'Type':['num','str','str'],'value':[1,2,7]})

def getDf(x):
  if x in range(0,9):
    return df[df.Type == 'num']
  else:
    return df[df.Type == 'str']
```

when using map like this:

```
 s1.map(getDf)    # or s1.apply(getDf)
```

I get A Sreis like this

```
0  Type  value
1  str      2
2  str      7
1  Type  value
0  num      1
2  Type  value
0  num      1
```

I was expected a dataframe result like this.

```
0  Type  value
1  str      2
2  str      7
3  num      1
4  num      1
```

Comment: Not sure why you expect this when you filter your df and return that, it returns a df

Comment: If you want that output you could `concat` on a list comprehension: `pd.concat([x for x in s1.map(getDf)], ignore_index=True)`

Comment: My original purpose is to query info from database which store in a datafrae (in sample that is 'df' ) according to a given series of different type element (that is 's1').  And I have to write it to csv file, so I expect the query result is dataframe.

Comment: Well it won't work the way you're doing it, it sounds like you want to filter your df using the series values also post a representative problem as what you're trying doesn't make much sense and is non-performant

Comment: Thank @EdChum . Yes. I need to change the way I handle my data.  Just a question about concat solution . Why series map in my example doesn't concat automactically?   But when using   s1.apply(lambda x :Series([x,x])), it will automatically concat series to dataframe.

Comment: you're creating a series in your comment code, in your posted code you return a df for each row, there's a semantic difference